# scroll the page to the spot of which display is block

Tags: jquery, css

I have an element at the middle of the page with display.none. I want when I change the display to block the page scroll to that spot. Is that possible?

Comment: how to you change element display in block ? using jQuery ? and once its display block page scroll ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you are using javascript to at some point change that element from "display: none" to "display: block" you could use some javascript to scroll to that element at the same time.

Edit: I just built this out real quick, it definitely works.

Explanation: atSomePoint is just whatever event is triggering the change from display: none to display: block. I am using .show() in order to take the element from hidden to block here, but there are obviously various ways you could do it. The scroll part comes in next. We are taking the body of the page and animating it; where to? Well, to the position of the element. So we animate using 'scrollTop' to the offSet that $(el) is from the top using '.offset().top'. There 500 is just how long the animation takes and the 'swing' is for the type of animation (easing) and it's not even necessary. Also, if you're curious about the stop(), that just stops any other current animations that are being executed. It would still work with this left out also.

```
(function() {
  $(el).atSomePoint, function() {
    $(this).show();
    $('html, body').stop().animate({
      'scrollTop': $(el).offset().top
    }, 500, 'swing');
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try using `ScrollTo` method --[MDN ScrollTo](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.scrollTo)

```
window.scrollTo(500,0); // (500,0) are the co-ordinates for the ScrollTo method
```

or you can try scrollTop method in Jquery [ScrollTop](https://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/)

```
$( "div.demo" ).scrollTop( 300 );
```

Answer (score 1):

try `window.scrollTo(x-coord,y-coord )`

```
x-coord is the pixel along the horizontal axis of the document that you want displayed in the upper left.

y-coord is the pixel along the vertical axis of the document that you want displayed in the upper left.
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.scrollTo